# Fixed background images jump when scrolling with a position fixed <video> on the page

Tags: css, video, html5-video

I've come across a strange problem and have no idea how to fix it. See the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9wqsr/1/

I have 3 divs and a video element. The video is position:fixed at the top of the page so the 3 divs scroll over it. The first has a solid colour background, the second has no background so the video is revealed when it scrolls over. The third has a background image that is fixed in it's position.

Here's the problem: when the 3rd div with the background image reaches the video, the "fixed" background image suddenly jumps.

This happens in the latest versions of Chrome and Safari but not Firefox.

Any idea what's going on and how to solve?

Comment: I see no reason for the #three background pic to be fixed. also, I don't see the pic on jsfiddle so cannot witness the jump

Answer (score -2):

Try the background image without the "fixed".

```
 background: yellow url(http://jsfiddle.net/img/top-bg.png) 10px 0 repeat;
```

Answer (score -3):

Try a background with `z-index:-1`;